# Wordpress posts loop show post_name / slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running this PHP code to loop through wordpress posts:

```
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_date();
    echo '<br />'; ?>
    <a href="/blog2/"><?php the_title(); ?></a>    
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <br><hr /><br>
    <?php
}
```

I want to be able to show the post_name or 'slug' of each post

I have tried using `echo $posts->post_name;` but it doesn't display anything

Answer (score 15):

You can get the title by `$post->post_title`

You can get the name/slug by `$post->post_name`

Answer (score 8):

You can get post by:

```
echo $post->post_name;
```

I have modified the code for you:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_date();
    echo '<br />'; ?>
    <a href="/blog2/"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  
    <?php  echo $post->post_name; ?>
   <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <br><hr /><br>
    <?php
}
?>
```